# Static libraries, dynamic libraries, DLLs, entry points, headers ... how to get out of this alive?

Tags: c++, architecture, dynamic, static

I recently had to program C++ under Windows for an University project, and I'm pretty confused about static and dynamic libraries system, what the compiler needs, what the linker needs, how to build a library ... is there any good document about this out there? I'm pretty confused about the *nix library system as well (so, dylibs, the ar tool, how to compile them ...), can you point a review document about the current library techniques on the various architectures?

Note: due to my poor knowledge this message could contain wrong concepts, feel free to edit it.

Thank you

**Feel free to add more reference, I will add them to the summary.**

---

**References**

Since most of you posted *nix or Windows specific references I will summarize here the best ones, I will mark as accepted answer the Wikipedia one, because is a good start point (and has references inside too) to get introduced to this stuff.

[Program Library Howto](http://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/) (Unix)

[Dynamic-Link Libraries (from MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682589.aspx) (Windows)

[DLL Information (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124549/dll-information) (Windows)

[Programming in C](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/) (Unix)

[An Overview of Compiling and Linking](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29930) (Windows)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124549/dll-information

Comment: @tunnuz - thanks for providing the summary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) - plenty of information there, and lots of links to other useful resources.

P.S. But perhaps it would be better to just ask a specific question about the problem you're currently having. Learning how to solve it may go a long way to teaching you the general concepts.

Comment: I don't have a real problem now, just wanted to know more about how libraries work under the various systems and how to create them.

Comment: Wikipedia as a teaching tool. I think you can do better.

Try these books:

Expert C Programming by Peter van der Linden
Inside the C++ Object Model by Stanley B. Lippman
Ruminations on C++: A Decade of Programming Insight and Experience by Andrew Koenig

And finally and more specifically for your immediate needs:
http://www.amazon.com/Windows-via-C-Pro-Developer/dp/0735624240/ref=pd_rhf_shvl_3

Comment: MaSuGaNa - I'm sure that a 2-3 hour look at the Wikipedia page and the articles it's pointing to is more like what the OP had in mind, surely than reading 4 large books of which only small parts deal with what he asked about - and you didn't even indicate which parts

Answer (score 2):

You can find some background information from this [article here](http://encyclopedia.kids.net.au/page/dy/Dynamically_linked_library).  It gives you the basic background.  I'm trying to locate something with diagrams.  This should be a good place to get started.

The fundamental differences between a static library and a DLL is that with the static library the code is compiled into your final executable whereas a dynamic link library involves linking in a "stub" library (into your application) which contains mappings to functions in a separate file (.dll).

Here's an MSDN entry on [creating a static Win32 Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx) which might also help you.
..another link to MSDN for [creating a Dynamic Link Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)..

Just found [this site](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29930) which covers definitions of basically all the aspect you've quoted.

Answer (score 1):

See if these are useful:

- [Static and dynamic libraries](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a1-static-and-dynamic-libraries/)
- [Program Library HOWTO](http://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 1):

There is always MSDN for windows related stuff:
Head page for dlls ->
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682589

For Unix my favorite reference manual:
Programming in C, UNIX System Calls and Subroutines using C ->
http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/

RM