# Import numpy without installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is there a way to import `numpy` without installing it?

I have a general application built into an `.exe` with PyInstaller.  The application has a plugin system which allows it to be extended through Python scripts.  The plugin import system works fine for basic modules (lone `.py` files, classes, functions, and simple packages).  Internally, it globs a plugin directory and then imports accordingly using `__import__` or `importlib.import_module`.

The application is built with minimal dependencies in order to reduce the overall size of the executable.  Also, it's not possible to know what dependencies a future plugin will require nor practical to include *everything*.  However, some plugins will inevitably require dependencies.  `numpy` is a good test case for solving this class of problems.

---

Here's what I've tried.

A wheel file is really just a directory.  It can be added to `sys.path` and the contents imported.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\path\to\numpy-1.16.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl")

import numpy as np
```

The wheel file is read, but the import generates an error.

```py
*** ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using c:\projects\zip_test\venv\Scripts\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

The puzzling part is that the wheel file contains a `.pyd` for `_multiarray_umath`.

```
C:\projects\zip_test\plugins\New folder\numpy\core>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is FE3D-6596

 Directory of C:\projects\zip_test\plugins\New folder\numpy\core

07/25/2019  02:37 PM    <DIR>          .
07/25/2019  02:37 PM    <DIR>          ..
    ....
04/22/2019  02:55 AM           101,376 _multiarray_tests.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
04/22/2019  02:55 AM         2,494,976 _multiarray_umath.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
    ....
              74 File(s)    583,173,551 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  309,925,851,136 bytes free
```

This feels like a pathing issue. Yet adding the direct path for `core/` to `sys.path` generates the same error.

```py
sys.path.append(r"C:\projects\zip_test\plugins\numpy-1.16.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl\numpy\core")
```

What's the deal?  Why can't Python find `numpy.core._multiarray_umath`?

---

In response to repsones:

- The wheel file was obtained from Christoph Gohlke.
- My operating system is Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.
- I am running `Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` (installed via Python Foundation build `3.6.8150.0`) in a `venv`.  The "system" Python is not on `PATH`.
- I can install the `numpy-1.16.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` file via `pip` and `import numpy as np` works fine.  I then uninstall `numpy` via `pip uninstall -y numpy`.

Running `dumpbin /dependents _multiarray_umath.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` produces:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.22.27905.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file _multiarray_umath.cp36-win_amd64.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    mkl_rt.dll
    python36.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll

  Summary

       77000 .data
        1000 .gfids
       1C000 .pdata
       30000 .rdata
        3000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
      1BD000 .text
```

Of the dependencies, I can find `mkl_rt.dll`, `python36.dll`, and `VCRUNTIME140.dll` in the either the `.whl` or the `venv`.  There are apparently two versions of `KERNEL32.dll`, one for x86 and one for x64.  One of these resides in `C:\Windows\System32`.

The only information I could find about the `api-ms-win-crt-*.dll` are described on [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) within the "Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows",

> The Windows 10 Universal CRT is a Windows operating system component
>   that enables CRT functionality on the Windows operating system. This
>   update allows Windows desktop applications that depend on the Windows
>   10 Universal CRT release to run on earlier Windows operating systems.

These are for non-Windows 10 systems.  There seems to be no "official" way to obtain them for a Windows 10 system.  I was able to copy the dlls from a Windows 7 system.  Naively putting them in the `PYTHONPATH` (not surprisingly) doesn't work.  If they were to work at all, they would likely need to be registered.  But 1) registering Windows 7 dlls on Windows 10, I am told, can make the system unstable and 2) definitely doesn't seem like a universal, portable solution.

Comment: The first questions are
1.) Where did you get the wheel from
2.) Are you using a 64 but machine 
3.) What python version do you have installed

Comment: @EdekiOkoh, Great questions! I have updated my question with responses and other relevant information.

Comment: always include the generic [python] tag in all python questions. use a version-specific tag at your discretion. Note, Python 3 *is* Python, Python 2 [is rapidly approaching it's end of life](https://pythonclock.org/). And more critically, maybe, most important Python projects [have pledge to require Python 3](https://python3statement.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending on how you define "install".

Numpy requires the use of `.pyd` files.  A pyd file is [essentially](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll) a [`dll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124550/5065796).  These are compiled code files which the Python interpreter references during run-time.  Unfortunately, the Windows API calls used to load dll files requires them to exist at the filesystem level.  When you try to import directly from a wheel, the pyd files (and the functions/classes they contain) aren't accessible.  Hence, the error.

## The (Relatively) Easy solution

One solution is to make the pyd files accessible on the filesystem.  To do that, it's probably simplest to unpack the whole wheel file to disk<sup>1</sup>.

In that case, consider "how you define 'install'":

- If you *could* run numpy straight from the wheel, wouldn't that mean numpy was installed?
- What difference does it really make whether you're writing a wheel file or the contents of that wheel file?

Since the plugin system is downloading a wheel file onto the filesystem, the application must have write access.  Download the wheel file and extract it into the plugins directory.  As long as the plugin directory is on the PYTHONPATH (i.e. `sys.path.append`), the import will work.  Smarts and so forth can be added from there.  Of course, what level of smarts you need is a whole other issue.  But that's the basic idea.

## The Wizard's Path

Another solution is to create your own functionality to import a dll from memory.  This is precisely the goal of Joachim Bauch's [MemoryModule project](https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule/tree/master/doc).  It seems the Py2Exe project used the MemoryModule at one point, through a module called [`zipextimporter.py`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190806201535/http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Hacks/ZipExtImporter).  Unfortunately, the code is hard to find and seems outdated (Python 2.4).  There is also a similar module called [`pymemimporter.py`](https://github.com/n1nj4sec/pymemimporter) which is slightly more recent.

---

<sup>1</sup> Numpy expects the pyd files to be in specific locations.  If you want to extract only the pyd files, they'll need to be nested in the appropriate folders (e.g. `numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`).  This is sufficient to import numpy, but unless the other modules are available, rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

First. 
Build application with and without numpy. Check difference between builds. 
`Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'` Can means two things:

1. cannot found file
2. some dependence of this this pyd file is not satisfied. You may try to check it with http://dependencywalker.com/.

Comment: Checking that right now.  Good to know I'm on the right track!

Comment: KERNEL32.dll is system site library. 

Maybe you need only to copy numpy whl to program directory for proper solving dll dependencies. Looking on the list it may be python36.dll